# Showing that the sequence converges knowing that three other sequences converge

Tags: analysis

I have a question in Analysis. Knowing that $x_{2n}$, $x_{2n-1}$, $x_{3n}$ converge, how can I show that $x_{n}$ converges?

Comment: Hint: You only need to know that two of those sequences converge, the other is a bit of a distraction.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I think we need the distraction too.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Yes e.g. $x_{2n}$ can converge to 1 and $x_{2n-1}$ can converge to -1.

Comment: Ah, cute. Yes, no distractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: 1) $x_{2n}$ and $x_{3n}$ should converge to the same limit (by looking at a profitable subsequence of each). 2) A similar argument for another profitable choice of two of $x_{2n}, x_{2n-1}, x_{3n}$. 3) All three given subsequences actually converge to the same limit. We can now conclude via $x_{2n},x_{2n-1}$.

Comment: By using which subsequence can I show that all three given subsequences converge to the same limit?

Comment: @MaryStar For $x_{2n}$ and $x_{3n}$ use, e.g. $x_{6n}$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MaryStar You are welcome.